# MappingException:The target-entity UserBundle\Entity\userRoles cannot be found in 'UserBundle\Entity\User#userRoles'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I'm a beginner with Symfony where I've been asked to create a User entity containing some informationS, using FOSUser
Everything went smoothly until when I tried to do the following line command

`php/bin console doctrine:schema:update --force`

At this moment I had the following error

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
>     The target-entity UserBundle\Entity\userRoles cannot be found in 'UserBundle\Entity\User#userRoles'.

I've tried to change some annotations but since I don't really know what I'm doing, this didn't really work

Here's the snippet of the entity

```
<?php
// src/UserBundle/Entity/User.php
namespace UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
* @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Username already taken")
*/
class User extends BaseUser{

    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

//    /**
//    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
//    * @Assert\NotBlank()
//    * @Assert\Email()
//    */
//    protected $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prenom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $prenom;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pseudo", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $pseudo;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="telephone", type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $telephone;

//    /**
//    *
//    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
//    */
//    protected $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="userRoles", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="userRoles")
     *
     */
    private $userRoles;





    /**
     * Set prenom
     *
     * @param string $prenom
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPrenom($prenom)
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get prenom
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrenom()
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * Set pseudo
     *
     * @param string $pseudo
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPseudo($pseudo)
    {
        $this->pseudo = $pseudo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pseudo
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPseudo()
    {
        return $this->pseudo;
    }

    /**
     * Set telephone
     *
     * @param string $telephone
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setTelephone($telephone)
    {
        $this->telephone = $telephone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get telephone
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTelephone()
    {
        return $this->telephone;
    }

    /**
     * Add userRole
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\Role $userRole
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addUserRole(\UserBundle\Entity\Role $userRole)
    {
        $this->userRoles[] = $userRole;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove userRole
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\Role $userRole
     */
    public function removeUserRole(\UserBundle\Entity\Role $userRole)
    {
        $this->userRoles->removeElement($userRole);
    }

    /**
     * Get userRoles
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getUserRoles()
    {
        return $this->userRoles;
    }
}
```

What's wrong with this code ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have a typo in the annotation, in accordion with the signature of 
set setter/getter method the targetEntity is not of `userRoles` class but seems of `UserBundle\Entity\Role` class.

So change the definition as follow:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\Role", inversedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="userRoles")
 *
 */
private $userRoles;
```

Hope this help